# Regex for searching in source code( while loop)

Tags: c, regex

I want to create regular expression which matches while(true) loop in which body is not used word '**argv**'

Example 1:

```
    while(true){ 
        for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++) printf("%s",argv[i]);
    }
```

*argv* is used in the body of while loop - reg ex **should not match** this

Example 2:

```
 while(true){ 
     for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) printf("%d",i);
 }
```

*argv* is not used in the body of while loop - reg ex **should match** this.

Till now i have just this regular expression:

```
while\s*\(\s*true\s*\)\s*\{ there_should_be_something \}
```

I dont know what to replace with there_should_be_something

Thanks a lot

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse non-regular languages like C can be rather difficult and non-rewarding. Consider using an actual parser.

Comment: @unwind i have to use reg ex

Comment: @anticol you have to use a parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that works on the examples above: `while\s*\(\s*true\s*\)\s*\{(([^}](?!argv))*)\}`

Explanation:

- `while\s*` matches `while`, then zero or more spaces
- `\(\s*true\s*\)` matches `(true)` and tolerates spaces
- `\{...\}` tolerates stuff between the braces
- The stuff within the braces is based on this: `[^}]*`, i.e. no braces are allowed within the braces. **This is a limitation** for the sake simple regex. If you want to deal with all the braces, I suggest to sue a real parser.
- This stuff within the braces is combined with [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html): `(?!argv)` which means anything that's not followed by `argv`.
- I.e. `[^}](?!argv)` means any non-brace character that's not followed by `argv`.
- We just group it and require this group zero or more times: `([^}](?!argv))*`